# How do I create a pure Dart package for a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a pure Dart package to be used in my Flutter app. Problem is that when building my app some Android and iOS specific files are generated under the library folder. I wonder if this is a bug or a known feature?

I have created the project using the command:

```
flutter create -t package mypackage
```

For example the generated file GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java looks like this:

```
package io.flutter.plugins;

import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;

/**
 * Generated file. Do not edit.
 */
public final class GeneratedPluginRegistrant {
  public static void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    if (alreadyRegisteredWith(registry)) {
      return;
    }
  }

  private static boolean alreadyRegisteredWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    final String key = GeneratedPluginRegistrant.class.getCanonicalName();
    if (registry.hasPlugin(key)) {
      return true;
    }
    registry.registrarFor(key);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Can I avoid generating those GeneratedPluginRegistrant.* files? If not, do I have to commit them to source control?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For pure dart packages, you need only one thing: a `pubspec.yaml`, with a name & environment constraints:

```
name: my_package
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0 <3.0.0"
```

This is enough to add `my_package` as a dependency to your flutter project though:

```
dependencies:
  my_package:
    path: ../path/to/my_package/folder
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with command line:

1. path to `pub` should be set in your environment variable like:

   C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\bin;
2. `pub global activate stagehand`
3. `mkdir dart_project`
4. `cd dart_project`
5. `stagehand package-simple`

*Generating it with command line will generate a bit of code for you which will give you an idea that how a package should be managed.*

You can use this project as dependency in pubspec.yaml file of your Flutter or Angular-Dart project as:

```
dependencies:
  dart_project:
    path: ../path/to/dart_project
```